# Use trimDirectiveWhitespaces under some condition only

Tags: jsp, whitespace, scriptlet

No matter how the condition is, the page directive in IF statement always run, it just ignores the condition.

Anyone knows how to setup page directive under condition?

```
<% if (condition) { %>
    <%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<% } %>
```

I tried `<c:if>` JSTL and `<jsp:directive.page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"/>`, but it is the same.

Comment: More information: if condition fails, the other regular statements in IF block won't run as expected, but page directive

Comment: JSP files are translated into servlets. The issue is page directives happen much earlier (after compilation) than your scriptlets. You should not be using scriptlets. In fact, some would say, JSP is mostly ignored and people use alternative web presentation layers. Of course, JSP is still being updated; perhaps there are many modern projects using it (and I just don't know it).